# Using XAudio2 in C

Tags: c, windows, audio, xaudio2

I am working on a C program using Visual Studio 2015 on Windows 10. When I include XAudio2.h I get a few hundred compiler errors, I believe the errors all stem from this one:

> Error C2485   'uuid': unrecognized extended attribute

Is there anyway to get XAudio2 working with a C application?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**In short, the latest versions of XAudio2 (XAudio 2.8 in the Windows 8.x SDK, XAudio 2.9 in the Windows 10 SDK) don't support C, only C++.**

The older XAudio 2.7 from the [deprecated DirectX SDK](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ee663275.aspx) builds with C, although it's had basically no testing from C. In fact, DirectX usage from C rather than C++ hasn't really been tested or well supported in a very, very long time. The MIDL compiler used for generating COM interface headers still has a lot of C-related support macros and elements from back when C usage was a first-class citizen, but this stuff is definitely in an "as is" state that gets little to no test coverage.

**You can continue to frustrate yourself, you can wrap all the C++ code up in your own C callable wrapper, or just start using C++.**

See [this post](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/chuckw/2015/08/05/where-is-the-directx-sdk-2015-edition/) and [this post](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/chuckw/2012/04/02/xaudio2-and-windows-8/) for important information about using VS 2015 with the legacy DirectX SDK.

Comment: Thanks, this was very informative. I had no idea C had limited support.

Comment: For games in particular, there was a time when C was very important--mostly Id Games and John Carmack pushed for it in the 90s. Since then, the C++ language and more importantly the quality of the compliers has greatly improved so there's not much value in having "pure C" support for applications--drivers are sometimes still written using C, but many use C++. You can always just use C++ as a "better C" if you are more comfortable with C at this point, and then organically use C++ language features as you gain proficiency.